# Best way to make an article model on Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

I'm making a site and I would like to be able to change the content from the Django's administration. What would be the best way in making something like a model called an Article and it has a title and content. I need to know how I would be able to choose a position for the article. Would the best way be something such as a CharField named for example home_main and just add those in the template. Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what is a position for article?

Comment: Like where on the page it is, like which div it would be inside of. What's the best way of getting a specific article?

Comment: Use something like [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/) or [Mezzanine CMS](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a CharField with choices to the Article model. I can image there will only be a set of fixed choices where an article can be positioned.

```
POSITION_CHOICES = (
    HOME_MAIN, "HOME_MAIN",
    BUTTOM_MAIN, "BOTTOM_MAIN",
    TOP_MAIN, "TOP_MAIN"
)


class Article(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_lenght=50, choices=POSITION_CHOICES)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/